MAUI: Issue with fetching current location
I am using below code to fetch the current location in my MAUI application.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NeedHelp.Conditional_Compilation
{
    public class GetCurrentLocations
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource;
        private bool _isCheckingLocation;
        public async Task GetCurrentLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                _isCheckingLocation = true;

                GeolocationRequest request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

                _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                Location location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

                if (location != null)
                    Preferences.Default.Set("latitude", location.Latitude);
                    Preferences.Default.Set("longitude", location.Longitude);
                Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Unable to get location
            }
            finally
            {
                _isCheckingLocation = false;
            }
        }

        public void CancelRequest()
        {
            if (_isCheckingLocation && _cancelTokenSource != null && _cancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }
}

I saved the latitude and longitude values to local DB and fetch it when saving to database like below.
GetCurrentLocations getcurrentLocations = new GetCurrentLocations();
await getcurrentLocations.GetCurrentLocation();
string latitude = Preferences.Default.Get("latitude", "");
string longitude = Preferences.Default.Get("longitude", "");
//API call to save the location details

My problem is the location details are not accurate when the user is moving. When the user moves I sent the updated location details using the above API to our database on every 5 seconds.
After saving the location details I call another API to fetch the saved locations and using that I draw a line on a map. But the line drawing is not correct, it has a major difference with the actual path the user gone.
The user move from A to B and then B to C. Check the below Screenshot. But the line showing on the map is different.

Code for drawing line on Map:
if (friendDetails.latitudeList.Count != 0 && friendDetails.longitudeList.Count != 0)
{
    latitude = 0.0;
    longitude = 0.0;
    bool validLocationFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < friendDetails.latitudeList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (friendDetails.latitudeList[i] != 0.0 && friendDetails.longitudeList[i] != 0.0)
        {
            latitude = friendDetails.latitudeList[i];
            longitude = friendDetails.longitudeList[i];
            validLocationFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (validLocationFound)
    {
        Location location = new Location(latitude, longitude);
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Location(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
        Pin pin = new Pin
        {
            Label = "",
            // Address = "The city with a boardwalk",
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Location = new Location(location.Latitude, location.Longitude)
        };
        map.Pins.Add(pin);
        geopin = pin;
    }
    else
    {
        map_layout.IsVisible = false;
    }

    // Determine the number of pairs to add (maximum of 5)
    int count = Math.Min(5, Math.Min(friendDetails.latitudeList.Count, friendDetails.longitudeList.Count));

    // Create a list to hold the valid latitude and longitude pairs
    List<Location> validCoordinates = new List<Location>();

    // Iterate through the latitude and longitude lists to find non-zero coordinates
    int validCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < friendDetails.latitudeList.Count && i < friendDetails.longitudeList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (friendDetails.latitudeList[i] != 0.0 || friendDetails.longitudeList[i] != 0.0)
        {
            validCoordinates.Add(new Location(friendDetails.latitudeList[i], friendDetails.longitudeList[i]));
            validCount++;

            // Stop once we have the required number of valid pairs
            if (validCount == count)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create the polyline
    Polyline polyline = new Polyline
    {
        StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb("#ea4333"),
        StrokeWidth = 5,
    };

    // Add valid points to the Geopath based on the available coordinates
    foreach (var location in validCoordinates)
    {
        polyline.Geopath.Add(location);
        //fix for the red line is not showing on the map
        map.MapElements.Add(polyline);
    }

    // Now you can use the polyline as needed
    geovalue = polyline;
    map.MapElements.Add(polyline);
    map_layout.IsVisible = true;
}
else
{
    map_layout.IsVisible = false;
}

I tried a lot but I didn't understood what is the real reason behind this issue. Is the location fetching has any issues? Is the line drawing on the map logic has any issues?

why are you using Medium accuracy?

@Jason What should I use instead of that? Best or High?

if you want more granularity you should use a higher accuracy setting.  Check the docs
